# Getting "Not Found" when wrapping styles in {#if} blocks in Svelte

Tags: css, svelte

I made a component in SvelteKit that will have different styles based on the data provided.
Part of the conditional styles are some background images that should be one of either two:

The `style` tag looks like this:

```html
{#if true}
  <style>
  ...
  .branch.ezzeddin {
      background-image: url('$lib/assets/ezzeddin-logo-minified.png');
  }
  ...
  </style>
{/if}
```

With this `{#if}` block I get the following error that the image doesn't exist, because somehow the compiler takes in the image url string *as is* and doesn't link to the actual image:

```
Error: Not found: /$lib/assets/ezzeddin-logo-minified.png
    at resolve (C:/Users/hosam/Desktop/Work/Dev/recruitement-interface/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:430:13)
    at resolve (C:/Users/hosam/Desktop/Work/Dev/recruitement-interface/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:277:5)
    at Object.#options.hooks.handle (C:/Users/hosam/Desktop/Work/Dev/recruitement-interface/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:49:56)
    at Module.respond (C:/Users/hosam/Desktop/Work/Dev/recruitement-interface/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:274:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

When I remove the `{#if}` block everything works fine, but some styles get applied that I don't want to.
And I don't want to separate the logic into two components because otherwise I'll end up with so many duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
use [H.B.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76870804/19078744)'s method in stead:

```html
<!-- div with conditional styling -->
<div class="branch" class:ezzedin={true} />

<style>
  ...
  .branch.ezzeddin {
    background-image: url('$lib/assets/ezzeddin-logo-minified.png');
  }
  ...
</style>
```

If for whatever reason you would still like to keep the import in the script tag you may do the following:

```html
<script>
  import logo from "$lib/assets/ezzeddin-logo-minified.png";
</script>

<!-- div with conditional styling -->
<div class="branch ezzedin" style="--logo-url:'{logo}'" />

<style>
  ...
  .branch.ezzeddin {
    background-image: url(var(--logo-url));
  }
  ...
</style>
```

Comment: I tried it but it seems that using interpolation doesn't work in css the way you put. I even tried without the quotes but no difference. And the syntax highlighting doesn't seem to notice that the image is being used.

Comment: I apologize, using a js variable with the svelte syntax isn't possible inside the <style> tag. in stead I edited my answer to use [H.B.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76870804/19078744)'s method.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try this. This probably also breaks scoping and style extraction because the style would not longer be treated as *the* component style tag.

If you want styles to apply conditionally, just add classes conditionally, e.g. using [`class:name` directives](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#class-name). With a CSS preprocessor<sup>1</sup> you then can just nest everything inside blocks.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Requires a Svelte preprocessor, like [the one from the Vite plugin](https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/blob/main/docs/preprocess.md).</sub>